# Can't find project Solution(.sln) 

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a ASP.NET C# project. Why am I not getting the solution(.sln) file of any project. 
When I close one project then on my project folder i dont get any .sln file, what is the reason and how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

You're not seeing a Solution in the Solution explorer?

1. Go to menu Tools >> Options
2. Select the tab General (under Projects and Solutions)
3. Check 'Always show solution'

[image: Options Window]

Answer (score 0):

In VStudio if you create a asp.net project/website the solution is stored in your `%USERPROFILE%\my documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects` folder.